# Libtorch only has cmake config file but needs to build with meson

Tags: cmake, meson-build, libtorch

I'm trying to make a cpp project that uses libtorch (C++ distributions of pytorch) using meson build.
It has one simple cpp file of about 50 lines that runs deep learning on images.

First, I confirmed that my project runs well in two environments.

1. Since meson uses the pkg-config file, I made a simple pkg-config file for libtorch, and it works for a project running on the CPU.
2. libtorch provides a TorchConfig.cmake file, so I used cmake to confirm that my project runs on the GPU version.

However, I don't know how to build the GPU version of the project using meson.
The TorchConfig.cmake file is more complicated than I thought, so it was very difficult to make it manually with the pkg-config file.
(TorchConfig.cmake file references many cmake files in libtorch directories.)

I also tried to use libtorch_dep = dependency('Torch', method : 'cmake'), but it only found libtorch.so among many libtorch libraries that are for GPU APIs.

So, how can I build the project using libtorch with only cmake config file like this with meson?
Or is there a way to utilize the cmake config file to write a pkg-config file?
Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.

operating system: Ubuntu 18.04
meson version: 0.54.0
cmake version: 3.22.1
libtorch version: 1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

I tried to leverage “method: cmake” in meson, but it fails.
So, I wrote pkg-config file for libtorch manually and it works now.